# Creating a log function with a custom base

Tags: objective-c, math, logging

I have a formula that uses a logarithm function with a custom base, for example: logarithm with a base of `b` and value of `x`. In Objective-C, I know there are `log` functions that calculate without a base and base of either `2` or `10`.

Is there a function that has the ability to calculate a `log` function with a custom/variable base? Or is there an alternative method of computing this formula?

The basic idea of my formula is this: `log1.02 1.26825`. This should equal `12.000`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Like this:

```
double logWithBase(double base, double x) {
    return log(x) / log(base);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can calculate *arbitrary* logarithms with `logbx = logcx / logcb`, where `c` is one of the more readily available bases such as `10` or `e`.

For your particular example:

- `loge1.26825 = 0.237637997`;
- `loge1.02 = 0.019802627`; and
- `0.237637997 / 0.019802627 = 12.0003268758`.

To five significant digits, that's `12.000`.

---

In fact, `1.0212` is actually `1.268241795` and, if you use *that* value rathet than the one you gave, you get much closer to twelve:

- `loge1.268241795 = 0.237631528`;
- `loge1.02 = 0.019802627`; and
- `0.237631528 / 0.019802627 = 12.000000197`.

Answer (score 1):

Ray is right but here is a Obj-C method modification of it:

```
-(double) logWithBase:(double)base andNumber:(double)x {
    return log(x) / log(base);
}
```

Comment: It makes no sense to have this as an instance method, since it doesn't make use of an instance. You might have it as a class method on a MathUtils class or something like that if you really want an Obj-C method and not just a C function.